Why is the default event action prevented when calling e.preventDefault() in the parent element?
The default action when pressing nav__link is to go to a certain section. When I don't have e.preventDefault() in the parent element, the default action of going to a section is executed. But when I place e.preventDefault() in the parent element, the default event action is not executed but console.log(e.defaultPrevented) prints false. Why is the default still prevented?
//Child ------------------------
document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link').forEach(function (val, i) {
  val.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    const id = this.getAttribute('href');
    document.querySelector(id).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    console.log(e.defaultPrevented); // false
  });
});


//Parent -------------------------------
document.querySelector('.nav__links').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log('parent');
  e.preventDefault();
});

I was expecting that the default action is going to be executed still

Hint: in what order do you get the logs?


console.log(e.defaultPrevented) prints false

because console.log(e.defaultPrevented) ran before you called preventDefault. The default event listener type is called as an event “bubbles” up from where it was originally dispatched to the element’s ancestors, so the child listener runs before the parent listener.
